# django gravatar not getting picked up as a module - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: django, gravatar

so here is my problem - the gravatar app (from google projects - here! http://code.google.com/p/django-gravatar/) in my django project crashed everything on startup.

i get this error `Error: No module named gravatar`

this is my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'dumpstown.dumpstownapp',
'bootstrap_toolkit',
'registration',
'gravatar'
)
```

and from the console when i run this:

```
>> import sys
>> print sys.path
['', 'C:\\development\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\development\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\developm
ent\\PycharmProjects\\lib\\gravatar', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:
\\development\\python\\DLLs', 'C:\\development\\python\\lib', 'C:\\development\\
python\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\development\\python\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\development
\\python', 'C:\\development\\python\\lib\\site-packages']
```

what am i missing here?

UPDATE
huh, weird. I've checked the gravatar folder, and i have

```
templatetags dir
__init__.py
models.py
views.py
```

also, if i change the installed apps section to read:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'dumpstown.dumpstownapp',
'bootstrap_toolkit',
'registration',
'templatetags'
)
```

then the server starts up fine and runs. But i... i'm all confused now! Am i meant to import the templatetags? or something else? how do i refer to the gravatar stuff if i'm importing templatetags??

EDIT: Solved.

I just don't understand how python works, it would seem! I was totally adding the wrong item to the pythonpath - i was adding `C:\\development\\PycharmProjects\\lib\\gravatar`, where i should have really been adding `C:\\development\\PycharmProjects\\lib`

this solved the problem, and now i can use gravatar as i want. The settings.py entry is as above in my first example (that is, just 'gravatar') and the way i use it is i just {% load gravatar %}

hurrah!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally adding the wrong item to the pythonpath - i was adding C:\development\PycharmProjects\lib\gravatar, where i should have really been adding C:\development\PycharmProjects\lib

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you checked out the trunk folder and have a structure like ..\gravatar\gravatar? The setup.py script should install it somewhere your path but you could also try changing `C:\developm ent\PycharmProjects\lib\gravatar` to `C:\developm ent\PycharmProjects\lib\gravatar\gravatar`

Comment: hm, no, the gravatar folder looks like this: templatetags folder, init, models and views py files